# Why can't my Triton land at a terror site?

Tags: x-com-terror-from-the-deep

I'm playing X-COM: Terror From The Deep and aliens have launched a terror attack.  I dispatched my Triton, targetting the terror site.  It arrives there and then straight away starts coming back.  The terror site vanishes from the map a moment later.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I sent my Triton to a terror site?  Are there some special requirements that I haven't met yet?

If you need more information to answer this, just tell me what else you need :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only requirements to get to a terror site is that the ship needs to be crewed, and you need to send it there. I would guess that if your triton isn't landing, it must not have a crew.

Alternatives could be that it doesn't have the gas to get there, or something related.

Comment: Bingo.  I somehow managed to take all the crew off the ship! :)  Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: Triton has enough gas to get anywhere on Earth. And back.